memcmp() behaviour different depending on pointer cast
I've been having trouble for hours now while trying to compare 2 seemingly identical structs.  I've looked into alignment and padding as possible issues but found none.  When I played around with different combinations of designated initialisation, and zero initialisation combined with strcpy(), I found that memcmp() returned either 1 or 0.  I hope I've finally narrowed down the problem into a single C file.
name     = my-lib
version  = 1.2.3.4.5
name     = my-lib
version  = 1.2.3.4.5

FAILED (res1) memcmp() = 1
FAILED (res2) memcmp() = 1
PASSED (res3)

is the output of:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DRIVERS_NAME_BUFF_SIZE          64
#define DRIVERS_VERSION_BUFF_SIZE       64

typedef const struct drivers {
    char name[DRIVERS_NAME_BUFF_SIZE];
    char version[DRIVERS_VERSION_BUFF_SIZE];
} const drivers;

void print_drivers(drivers drvers) {
    printf("name     = %s\n", drvers.name);
    printf("version  = %s\n", drvers.version);
}

int main() {
    drivers before = {
        .name    = "my-lib",
        .version = "1.2.3.4.5"
    };
    drivers after = {0};
    strcpy(after.name, "my-lib");
    strcpy(after.version, "1.2.3.4.5");
    
    print_drivers(before);
    print_drivers(after);
    printf("\n");

    /****************
     * res1
     ***************/
    int res1 = memcmp((uint8_t *)(&before), (uint8_t *)(&after), sizeof(drivers));
    if (res1 != 0) {
        printf("FAILED (res1) memcmp() = %d\n", res1);
    } else {
        printf("PASSED (res1)\n");
    }

    /****************
     * res2
     ***************/
    int res2 = memcmp(&before, &after, sizeof(drivers));
    if (res2 != 0) {
        printf("FAILED (res2) memcmp() = %d\n", res2);
    } else {
        printf("PASSED (res2)\n");
    }

    /****************
     * res3
     ***************/
    uint8_t * base_before = &before; 
    uint8_t * base_after  = &after;
    int res3 = memcmp(base_before, base_after, sizeof(drivers));
    if (res3 != 0) {
        printf("FAILED (res3) memcmp() = %d\n", res3);
    } else {
        printf("PASSED (res3)\n");
    }
}

I'll quickly note that removing both consts from the typedef "fixes" the problem in that all memcmp()s return 0.  I don't understand this, can someone please explain it to me.  Thank you

You try to modify constant structures. That will lead to undefined behavior.

@Someprogrammerdude Ok, but the printed output is the same, and when I manually compare every byte in the 2 structs I find no differences, so I still don't understand why memcmp() says they're different

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen.

I get PASSED for each of the compares. So as pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude you are into the territory of undefined behaviour.

When I run it with GCC14 I can see two FAILED and the last one PASSED - and I can see from the assembly that the compiler has just statically emitted 1 as the result of memcmp. This is obviously allowed due to Undefined Behaviour, so now your question becomes "but why does GCC behave this way?" But the answer is the same: Undefined Behaviour can do anything. It's not defined.

@Useless That's handy to know.  I should really have checked the assembly myself before posting, so thank you

"I found that memcpy() returned either 1 or 0." You are mixing memcpy with memcmp Your code does not contain memcpy.

And why are you using casts?  The memcmp() prototype is int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);, and C requires no casting to or from void *.

Why do you have const in the typedef twice?

Undefined behavior is a characteristic of a whole program.  Although UB hinges on using (or misusing) specific constructs and / or evaluating particular expressions, it is not necessarily localized to the constructs and expressions that produce it.  For instance, that you observe an attempt to modify a const object to in fact have the desired effect on memory, as opposed to failing then and there, does not make it safe to assume that you're afterward in the clear, as if the object had not actually been const.

@AndrewHenle res2 was failing while res3 was passing, and the only difference appeared to be the use of different pointer types, so I thought I'd try casting to be sure

@Barmar thanks, second one shouldn't be there

The code has many warnings that shouldn't be ignored!
Anyway, just as others have pointed out, the problem you are facing is due to the undefined behavior created by writing on const structures.
The compiler is smart enough to replace the first two memcmp with a fixed 1 value, given that they are declared const and are initialized with different values, and being the before struct bigger than the after one in the memcmp evaluation.
But... if you add a volatile keyword to the declaration of the structures, as in:
volatile drivers before = {
    .name    = "my-lib",
    .version = "1.2.3.4.5"
};
volatile drivers after = {0};

Then all the tests pass: the compiler doesn't optimize anymore the memcmp calls, because it doesn't assume their values due to the volatile keyword on the variables' definition:
PASSED (res1)
PASSED (res2)
PASSED (res3)

